# Anyone know of a hosted TeamCity build provider?

Tags: continuous-integration, hosting, teamcity

I'm looking to set up a TeamCity server for continuously building a .NET web application. I already have hosting, so I don't want to get a whole new hosting account such as AppHarbor.

I don't maintain my own physical server, nor do I want to.

I also don't want to have to pay $50 or more per month for an entire dedicated Windows machine, just to host TeamCity.

I really don't care if it's slow and on a shared machine, as it's just continuous build which will be running in the background.

I'll want to have the outputs automatically deployed to a server of my choice through FTP.

Is there anyone on the market providing hosted TeamCity environments?

Comment: I think the main thing is here is, how much would you pay for it?

Comment: I'm surprised JetBrains doesn't offer this, especially since they offer hosted YouTrack. You'd think there'd be a (paying) market for this, and it would behoove them to offer the 2 apps bundled.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[AppVeyor CI](http://www.appveyor.com) provides hosted continuous integration for .NET developers.

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of this service.

Comment: i think teamcity is the only CI sever right now with nuget deployment and an internal nuget feed server which i think gives them a distinct advantage over other CI implementations on the market right now

Comment: @ChrisMcGrath, [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget) is an internal NuGet feed server that also does NuGet deployments. It can also be used with [BuildMaster](http://inedo.com/buildmaster/overview), made by the same group. I'm using BuildMaster for my main ASP.NET app and ProGet for internal libraries. They're both free; BuildMaster only for a limited number of users, applications, etc..

Comment: @chris-mcgrath I'm using AppVeyor's internal NuGet feeds with great successs.

Answer (score 11):

If your open source project you can get a free account at Code Better http://codebetter.com/jameskovacs/2009/02/24/announcing-teamcity-codebetter-com/  I don't know of any for non open source.

Comment: This is only for open source, if I don't have a licence what should I do

Comment: @Tushar http://choosealicense.com/ , prolly a couple months too late

Answer (score 0):

Just came across [BuildBox](https://buildbox.io/) (now [Buildkite](https://buildkite.com)) from a [tweet](https://twitter.com/toolmantim/status/504062359900413952) from [someone I follow](https://twitter.com/toolmantim). Seems like a suitable solution to this.

Comment: its not hosted teamcity, so not really.

Comment: Another alternative, also not TeamCity, would be Travis-CI, though it only works for Mono.

Answer (score 0):

[OnCheckin.com](https://oncheckin.com) offers Cloud Powered Continuous Deployment for.Net websites and services.

Disclosure: I am the developer and founder of this service.