# Online CI build server integrated with github for .NET projects

Tags: .net, github, continuous-integration

Is there any online CI build server which integrate with github for .NET projects?

I know only [travis](https://travis-ci.org/) but it isn't support .NET projects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Anyone know of a hosted TeamCity build provider?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884213/anyone-know-of-a-hosted-teamcity-build-provider)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Teamcity is a great CI tool with really good support for .NET. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884213/anyone-know-of-a-hosted-teamcity-build-provider) question covers hosted solutions. I think there is even one that's free if your project is open source.

Answer (score 2):

> I know only travis but it isn't support .NET projects.

Actually, **[Travis](http://travis-ci.org)** can build and run the tests of a .Net project on both Linux and MacOSX, through **[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/)**, an *"open source implementation of Microsoft's .NET Framework"*.

Provided your project doesn't rely on Windows-only API, this should work perfectly.

As an example, the **[LibGit2Sharp project](http://libgit2sharp.com)** leverages Travis to do just this.

- Travis **[build .yml file](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/.travis.yml)**
- Example of a Travis .Net/Mono **[build on both Lnux and Mac OSX](https://travis-ci.org/libgit2/libgit2sharp/builds/24787939)**

Comment: Mono doesn't support WPF :(